# Dark Souls 2: Xbox360 vs PlayStation 3 vs Xbox One vs PlayStation 4

Tags: dark-souls-2, framerate

Is there a graphical/framerate/draw distance/weapon change difference between these 4 versions (Xbox360 vs PlayStation 3 vs Xbox One vs PlayStation 4) of Dark Souls 2/Dark Souls 2: Scholar of the First Sin?

Comment: There is. The new gen version (PS4/XBO) has improved graphics, better framerate (60 FPS instead of 30) and is supposedly more difficult due to some places having more enemies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scholar of the First Sin runs at 1080p and 60fps, unlike the original version. As a result of it running in 60fps there is a bug where weapons degenerate more quickly than they should. This is going to be fixed in a patch in the near future.

http://www.gamespot.com/articles/new-dark-souls-ii-patch-finally-fixes-year-old-dur/1100-6426819/

Comment: Not so much a "bug", more just a side effect of the higher frame rate. This also occurred on the PC version of the original.

Comment: @Ben - Unless they intended it to have that effect, sounds like a bug to me ;)